# my code is not working on action method

Tags: php, javascript

This code use for display report on front end and in csv file also displa  this code running properly and this code is redirect on same page document.frmmonthly.action ="test2.php";  but second code is not working properly the code is not redirect to other page what is reason or what's the problem in my code......
document.frmmonthly.action ="csv.php";

action method is not working on csv.php.....my code is not working plz help me...

```
<head> 
    <script language="text/javascript">
        function OnSubmitForm(value) {    
           if(value == 'Generate')  {
              document.frmmonthly.action ="test2.php";
           } else if(value == 'Download') {
              document.frmmonthly.action ="csv.php";
           }

           return true;
       }    
    </script>
    </head>
    <form method="POST" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" 
                               onSubmit="OnSubmitForm(this.value)" 
                               value="Generate"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" 
                               onSubmit="OnSubmitForm(this.value)" 
                               value="Download" action="csv.php">
        </tr>       
    </form>
```

Comment: you dont have form with name "frmmonthly"..!

Comment: Also, `action` is not a valid attribute for `input`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST" name="frmmonthly" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
```

[Edit:] Also you have to rename onSubmit e.g. to onClick

Comment: +1 and small note: onsubmit should be changed to onclick on buttons only.

Comment: document.frmmonthly.action ="csv.php"; i create new file csv.php in the file fetch data form database but when i click on <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" onSubmit="OnSubmitForm(this.value)" value="Download">
    </tr>  this button not going on csv.php file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function OnSubmitForm(value)
{

if(value == 'Generate')
{
document.frmmonthly.action ="test2.php";
}
else if(value == 'Download')
{
document.frmmonthly.action ="csv.php";
}

    return true;
}

</script>
</head>
<form method="POST" name="frmmonthly" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">
     </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" onSubmit="OnSubmitForm(this.value)" value="Generate"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" onSubmit="OnSubmitForm(this.value)" value="Download">
    </tr>   

</form>
```

I remove action=".." from input type

Comment: not working dude......what the changes u done in this code...form name i already mention....

Answer (score 0):

Ypu should name your form:

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" name="frmmonthly">
```

Since the form doesn't have a name, your method can't set it's action.